# Rename a variable in the workspace through a list of names in a cell - MATLAB

Tags: excel, matlab, matrix, cell

I have some data in an excel file.

At first, I read the file and create a list of names stored in a cell through this command:

```
[status,sheets] = xlsfinfo(filename);
```

and I get:

```
sheets = {'A1','A2','B1','B2','C1'};
```

(these are the names of excelsheets in the excel file)

and through some process I obtain a matrix for each of these names (excelsheets). The final matrix for each is called:

```
completeData = [x,v,z,y,s];
```

Now, I want to:

1. change the name of "completeData" variable to each of its corresponding excelsheet (from the "sheets" cell).
2. then save this newly renamed variable (the old "completeData") with the name of its corresponding excelsheet (again from the "sheets" cell).

So far, I have only managed to save each completeData matrix resulting for each excel sheet separately with the name of the sheets [which is point number 2] through this command:

```
save(sprintf('%s',sheets{excelSheet}),'completeData');
```

(here I have a loop over "excelsheet")

The problem is that when I have mange excel sheets, and save all of them in a folder my hard disk, whenever I run any of these saved variables I get "completeData" in the workspace which is not what I want. I want to get also the name of the excelsheet.

How can I do this?

P.S. through this command:

```
eval(sprintf([sheets{excelsheet} '=completeData;']));
```

(again another loop over excelsheet)

I have managed to create several matrices with the names of excel sheets. But I do not know how I can save these very good newly created variables through a loop so that I do not do it one by one.

Comment: Using eval, and having "dynamic variables" (variables that change name/are created iteratively) are both terrible terrible programming practices. Whenver you need to do either of them, it means that your algorithms is worngly defined and you are just doing it worng

Comment: @PeyM87 As an alternative, you can use structs with [variable field names](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/generate-field-names-from-variables.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is how it worked:

First read information:

```
[status,sheets] = xlsfinfo(filename);

NamesList = sheets(:,1);
```

Now, apply the primarily collected information to read again with details:

```
for ind = 1:length(NamesList)

    % Only read those particular sheets

    [num,txt,raw] = xlsread(filename,NamesList{ind,:});

    var.(NamesList{ind})={txt(:,MyColumn),num};

    clear num txt raw

end
```

Answer (score 1):

Following up the comments above, I tried to write you a simplified example:

```
%% Initialise

names = {'name1', 'name2', 'name3'};
data  = randn(10, 3);

%% it create three fields called name1, name2 and name3 from data, in s

for ind=1:size(data, 2)
    s.(names{ind}) = data(:, ind);
end
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: With a very little change (adding "read from Excel file with X sheet name" after the first line of FOR loop), this worked perfectly. Thanks.